# Disable individual dates in angular-strap 2.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-strap

Using angular-strap v0.7 I was able to use Bootstrap's beforeShowDay method to disable/enable specific dates in the datepicker.

In angular-strap 2.0 I can't seem to find this option. Does it exist?

I'm building a payment system that lets users schedule payments for future dates, but I only want to allow them to select valid business days. I have an API request that returns an array of valid dates, excluding weekends and federal holidays. I need to disable selection of those weekend and holiday dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the angular-strap repository at https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap I noticed that less than 24 hours before the question was posted a commit was made to add this functionality. It is not included in the v2.0.3 release, so it will probably be in a future v2.0.4 release.

To disable specific ranges of dates, pass the directive an array via the `disabled-dates` attribute. This array consists of objects of the type {start: new Date(2014, 03, 03), end: new Date(2014, 03, 05)} that specify date ranges to disable.

This attribute does NOT do 2-way binding. Once the directive has been compiled and linked changes to this array will not propagate.

For more information see the commit message at https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/commit/bb5038064a681842539984d5626ea550ff3c4c8e. Once this feature is released I expect the docs will be updated at http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##datepickers.